# How to set field name in Gson, if it comes as value?

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I have next Json :

```
{
  "Regions": [
    {
      "Id": "NA",
      "Label": "North America"
    },
    {
      "Id": "EUR",
      "Label": "Europe"
    },
    {
      "Id": "ASIA",
      "Label": "Asia"
    },
    {
      "Id": "AUS",
      "Label": "Australia"
    }
  ],
  "Stations": {
    "EUR": [
        "Kiyv",
        "Astana"
    ],
    "NA": [
        "Kosovo"          
    ]
  }
}
```

As you see key names in `Stations` section is the same as values of each item in `Regions` section.

My POJO classes

```
public class Provisions {
    @SerializedName("Regions")
    public List<Region> regions;

    @SerializedName("Stations")
    public List<Station> stations;
}

public class Region {
    @SerializedName("Id")
    public String id;

    @SerializedName("Label")
    public String label;
}

public class Station {
     // what should be put here?
}
```

And my question is : how to declare POJO in more elegant manner,  to make my life easier in future : for ex: if backend add new Region and Station, I will not want modify POJO - all will parse automatically.

<sub>*Maybe it will complete via generics?*</sub>

Comment: right now `Stations` is map of strings to list of strings ... not list of `Station` ... so `Map<String, List<String>> stations` should work and should work if you would add new Region or Station

Answer (score 0):

Redefine your Provisions class as follows:

```
public class Provisions {
    @SerializedName("Regions")
    private List<Region> regions;

    @SerializedName("Stations")
    private Map<String, List<String>> stations;
}
```

Then you can deserialize using code similar to:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
Provisions provisions = gson.fromJson(JSON_VALUE, Provisions.class);
```